# Disable the CASCADE policy for deletion

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

I'm working with SQLAlchemy and with an auto-generated model (cf. [automap_base()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.automap_base)).
I would like to know if there is a simple way to disable the `DELETE ON CASCADE` default mechanism of SQLAlchemy.